# How to do a merge using Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK and TfvcHttpClient

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I want to merge a changeset from one TF branch to another using Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK and TfvcHttpClient.
Simply put, I wish to replicate this behaviour using the "Azure DevOps Services .NET SDK" instead of using tf.exe:

```
c:\projects>tf merge /version:C137~C137 branch1 branch2 /recursive
```

I can already successfully load branches using this:

```
TfvcBranch branch1 = tfvcHttpClient.GetBranchAsync(project: "A Project", path: "$/branch1").Result;
TfvcBranch branch2 = tfvcHttpClient.GetBranchAsync(project: "A Project", path: "$/branch2").Result;
```

and I can successfully load changesets using this:

```
TfvcChangeset changeset = tfvcHttpClient.GetChangesetAsync(137).Result;
```

Just the missing part of the puzzle is how to merge the changeset 137 from branch1 to branch2.

Please Note: before locking this down as a duplicate, the source control is on a TFS server, not GIT, so can't use GitHttpClient or Pull Requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no REST API methods that allow you to perform TFVC merges.

You will have to use the older SOAP-based [`ExtendedClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) package or rely on the `tf`.